# Insert tag inside a specific range - algorithm for DOM tree modification

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, dom

I need an algorithm for manipulating DOM tree.

For example I have this HTML code:

```
<div>
    This is 
    <b>interesting</b> 
    <a href="...">
        con
        <i>tent</i>
    </a>
    . It 
    <i>can be</i> 
    edit by users
</div>
```

User selects text "*is interesting content. It can*" and presses a button on the website. An event *onClick* of the button calls a function *insertTag('u')*.

After this the HTML code should look like this:

```
<div>
    This 
    <u>is 
        <b>interesting</b> 
        <a href="...">
            con
            <i>tent</i>
        </a>
        . It 
    </u>
    <i>
        <u>can</u>
        be
    </i> 
    edit by users
</div>
```

What should *insertTag()* function do? I googled, but I didn't find any examples and algorithms for this problem.

Comment: What is the logic inserting `u` tags? Looks pretty random to me. To get started, you could read about [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range) and [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) objects.

Comment: In the simplest way it should be look like this: 
<div>
    This 
    <u>is 
        <b>interesting</b> 
        <a href="...">
            con
            <i>tent</i>
        </a>
        . It 
    
    <i>
        can</u>
        be
    </i> 
    edit by users
</div>
In the start and the end of user's range we add _<u>_ and _</u>_
But it's incorrect because it's not right with the standard